# 2013-07-29 06:35:40:622 GMT to 2013/07/29 con 2013/07/29 tipo Date y no String

Tags: java

tengo ese formato de fecha `2013-07-29 06:35:40:622 GMT` y quiero de este sacar este formato 2013/07/29, he visto que con `format` de `SimpleDateFormat` se puede pero me devuelve un `String` y yo quiero `2013/07/29` en formato `Date`.

Se puede o no ?

Comment: Hola Yassine. Para mejorar tu pregunta, sería mejor que incluyas el código que has intentado.

Comment: Me parece que esto es un malentendido. Una cosa es tener la fecha en cierto formato (que será una cadena) y otra es tener una variable de tipo fecha (para poder realizar operaciones con ella).

Comment: Si quieres una variable Date no tiene sentido hablar de formato. O quieres el formato que comentas (string) o bien quieres la Date.

Comment: es que yo estoy trabajando en proyecto que esta montado asi, tengo un calendar que me devuelve un formato X y tengo que sacar de la base de dato un dato comparando esa fecha de formato X con un campo en la base de datos de tipo fecha pero de formato Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta de Joacer te dice como convertir, sin embargo creo que tu duda viene más a un problema de percepción de Date de parte de base de datos.

En Java el Objeto Date guarda en un long el epochtime en milisegundos, por lo que será lo mismo 2013-07-29 06:35:40:622 GMT que   2013/07/29 en el date.

Si tu necesitas un Date para base de datos necesitas la clase Date de SQL y no puedes trabajar las dos vía import por lo que una de ellas deberás llamarla con su nombre canónico. java.util.Date o java.sql.Date

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que siguiendo estos pasos puedes conseguir la transformación de fecha que quieres:

1. Convertir el texto de la primera fecha en un objeto Date
2. Convertir la fecha Date al segundo formato que se quiere
3. Crear el objeto Date con la nueva fecha formateada

Un código aproximado sería el siguiente:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); //He puesto este formato, pero puedes poner el que más se adecue a tus necesidades
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

    try{
         //Convertimos el texto de la primera fecha en un objeto Date
         Date fecha = sdf.parse("2013-07-29 06:35:40");

         //Convertimos la fecha Date al segundo formato que queremos              
         String fecha2 = sdf2.format(fecha );

         //Creamos el objeto Date con la nueva fecha formateada
         Date fecha = new Date(fecha2 );
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda

Comment: Gracias Joacer por tu ayuda

Comment: De nada @Yassine espero te haya servido de ayuda